# How to setup a stored procedure with incremental dates in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am new to Power BI. I am using an SQL [stored procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure) to get the data.

```
execute ED_DS_TRANS_DETAIL01 @DateFrom ='2022-09-20', @DateTo = '2022-09-20'
```

It does give me the required data but I want it to be incremental. For example, today is the `20th` and tomorrow is the `21st`. So I want to set up the power bi in such a way that it gets the `21st` data and then the next data `22nd` and so on. Also, it doesn't replace the previous date data and places the next data underneath the previous one.

---

I have tried the given solution

```
let
  Source = (Query as text) => let
  Source = Sql.Database("IP", "DB" , [Query=Query, CreateNavigationProperties=false])
  in
  Source
  in
  Source

let
tdy = Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()),
yest = Date.AddDays(tdy , - 1),
sQuery = Table.FromRecords({
    [sQuery = "execute ED_DS_TRANS_DETAIL01 @DateFrom ='" & Date.ToText(yest,[Format="yyyy-MM-dd"]) & "', @DateTo = '" & Date.ToText(tdy,[Format="yyyy-MM-dd"]) & "'"
    ]}),
#"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(sQuery, "Query2", each #"Fnc Query"([sQuery]))
in
#"Invoked Custom Function"
```

**GUI**

[image]

When I click "OK" button I am getting `Details: "Microsoft SQL: Incorrect syntax near '='."`

Comment: You must build an ETL process and store the results in a database. Each execution of the ETL should append the new rows to the existing. Then the report should be built to use this database (instead of the original data source).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it at the Power Query side...

First create the *parameters* of `dBaseIP` and `dBase` in case you may need to change it later...

Then create a custom function which will run the SQL query *"New Query"* → *Other Sources* → *"Blank Query"*.

```
let
      Source = (Query as text) => let
      Source = Sql.Database(dBaseIP, dBase , [Query=Query, CreateNavigationProperties=false])
in
      Source
in
      Source
```

At last, create the below function which will update your query as per today's date...

```
    let
    tdy = Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()),
    yest = Date.AddDays(tdy , - 1),
    sQuery = Table.FromRecords({
        [sQuery = "execute ED_DS_TRANS_DETAIL01 @DateFrom ='" & Date.ToText(yest,[Format="yyyy-MM-dd"]) & "', @DateTo = '" & Date.ToText(tdy,[Format="yyyy-MM-dd"]) & "'"
        ]}),
    #"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(sQuery, "Query2", each #"Fnc Query"([sQuery]))
in
    #"Invoked Custom Function"
```

[Check this sample file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J8heNdffXE8EljP1Itrn1BjqNoCWxQpp/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100599386090580961037&rtpof=true&sd=true)... Change the database IP and name and then try to run it...

Comment: So i have create the both in Power Query right ??

Comment: @Moeez yes and also two parameters in case you need to change the server and database later...

Comment: ok but first I have to load the database right ??

Comment: Kindly check my update I have tried your solution

Comment: @Moeez did you add these queries with ``"New Query" -> Other Sources --> "Blank Query"`` ?

Comment: @Moeez these are not SQL queries, these are power queires...

Comment: Yes I did also add tried to add these queries in `Blank Query` but it doesn't gives me any result :(

Comment: @Moeez i added a sample file... please check...

Comment: I have opened your file but didn't find any helpful material the query that you have mentioned `execute ED_DS_TRANS_DETAIL01 @DateFrom ='2022-09-25', @DateTo = '2022-09-26'` is already used by me. So what is the difference?

Comment: @Moeez when you open the file tomorrow, it will give you execute ``ED_DS_TRANS_DETAIL01 @DateFrom ='2022-09-26', @DateTo = '2022-09-27'`` everyday it will change according to the Today's date

Comment: how did you set it ?

Comment: ``tdy = Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow()),
    yest = Date.AddDays(tdy , - 1),``

Comment: @Moeez if you change the server IP and database name in my sample file, it should work fine if you have the right credentials...

Comment: That's what I am asking from where in your file I can change the credentials ?

Comment: open Power Query and find the [Data Source Settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-data-source-settings-and-permissions-power-query-9f24a631-f7eb-4729-88dd-6a4921380ca9) icon , there you can set the credentials and also on the ``Parameter`` side , you can set your servername and database name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248380/discussion-between-moeez-and-umut-k).